# Ruby insert method inserts element to wrong index

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a question on app Academy's practice questions.

> Write a method that takes in a string and an array of indices in the
> string. Produce a new string, which contains letters from the input
> string in the order specified by the indices of the array of indices.

I tried using Ruby's insert method to solve it:

```
def scramble_string(string, positions)
  
  arr = []
  indx = 0
  positions.each do |x|
    arr.insert(x,string[indx])
    indx += 1
  end
  return arr.join("")
end
puts scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0])  # for testing
puts scramble_string("markov", [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0])  # for testing

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts("\nTests for #scramble_string")
puts("===============================================")
    puts(
      'scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0]) == "dbca": ' +
      (scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0]) == "dbca").to_s
    )
    puts(
      'scramble_string("markov", [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0]) == "vkaorm"): ' +
      (scramble_string("markov", [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0]) == "vkaorm").to_s
    )
puts("===============================================")
```

For the first check "abcd", it outputted the correct answer "dbca", but when the second test runs, I get a wrong answer "vrokam". The correct answer is supposed to be "vkaorm". I can't figure out why my code isn't working for the second check. Any help is appreciated.

## EDIT:

I found the mistake in my code. Instead of

```
arr.insert(x,string[indx])
```

the correct code should be

```
arr.insert(indx,string[x])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method **insert** change size of array.

You can understand what happend with this code:

```
def debug_array(arrr)
  puts "---------------- #{arrr.size}, #{arrr.join('.')}"
end

def scramble_string(string, positions)

  arr = Array.new(string.size)
  indx = 0
  positions.each do |x|
    puts "#{indx} >> #{string[indx]}"
    arr.insert(x,string[indx])
    indx += 1
    debug_array arr
  end
  return arr.join("")
end
puts scramble_string("abcd", [3, 1, 2, 0])  # for testing
puts scramble_string("markov", [5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 0])  # for testing
```

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is there a method that works like insert without changing the size of the array?

Comment: juste do `arr[x] = string[indx]`